# have single commit after git pull

Tags: git

im working on feature's branch on my project actually i wanna send merge request as one commit . i have commited my changes and i have sent merge request now i have another change on my feature first i ran

```
git pull origin develop
```

it gives some changes for develop branch and appears new commit on `git log` as `Merge branch 'develop' of ...`

how can i change things again i put it on my own previous commit and send merge request as one commit?

what is the best practice?

Comment: This is where a git rebase is useful.

Comment: [`git pull origin develop --rebase`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt--r)

Comment: @SteveTomlin could you tell me how it works in this case?

Comment: The best practice is _don't_. Do not change the history of an already opened pull request. You can squash the feature branch when the PR has been approved and you merge it to develop, but do not attempt to squash it now that you have pushed it and the PR is open.

Comment: @matt Best practice is to not change the history of a PR, but squash is OK? I feel like that is highly situationally dependent. With this probably being GitLab, and therefore most likely a private repo, I would lean the other way: keep rewriting and make your branch perfect, and then perhaps regular merge or semi-linear merge it with `-no-ff`. Without too much thought I might even prefer that as the default in a public repo as well, compared to squash. (As long as the tool being used can compare PR version history for each push, which GitLab can do.)

Comment: @TTT well in that case the reverse merge was arguably wrong. If we're free to rewrite history, rebase onto develop instead, add the new commit, then squash it down using soft reset or interactive rebase.

Comment: At this point what I would do is reset hard to the first commit, rebase onto develop, cherry pick the second commit, and squash.

Comment: @matt I agree the reverse merge was wrong, and OP realized that too and that's why the question was asked. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note what you should have done in the first place, in order to avoid the merge commit, is with your branch checked out:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/develop

# or, the equivalent command by slightly tweaking what you did:
git pull --rebase origin develop
```

That would have rebased your 1 (or 2) commits on top of `origin/develop` instead of merging `origin/develop` into your branch. Note at this point you actually can still do the same rebase, because rebasing will drop the merge commit by default, so if you run either of the above options, you'll end up with your 2 commits on top of `origin/develop`.

Now you can squash those two commits together if you wish, using any of the various squashing methods, such as interactive rebase (`git rebase -i @~2`), or resetting (soft) back two commits (`git reset --soft @~2`) and recommitting, similar to [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75843881/184546).

Any time you rewrite your branch after you already pushed it, you'll need to force push to update your branch on the remote (which should also automatically update your Merge Request), so you can use:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've said in a comment, I don't think it's good to rewrite history on an already submitted PR. But you can do it if you like. Your current situation is not very clearly specified in the question but I'm going to assume it looks like this (most recent commit at top, time runs backwards as we go downwards):

```
aaaaaa (HEAD > myFeatureBranch) my second commit
bbbbbb the merge commit from develop
cccccc my first commit
dddddd [some commit reachable from develop]
```

Then I would write down the SHA of "my second commit" and say this:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard cccccc
git rebase origin/develop
git cherry-pick aaaaaa
git reset --soft origin/develop
git commit -m 'my one commit'
git push --force
```

Comment: I don't think we can assume OP has a local `develop`. Also, maybe you can omit the first 3 commands completely as they wouldn't change the current state? Maybe remove those and then just change the 4th to `git reset --soft origin/develop` ?

Comment: Tiny side note about using `origin/develop` instead of `develop`, is if OP has fetched more commits after the merge commit was created, the state wouldn't be identical, so your full set of 6 commands might be necessary, but just replace `develop` with `origin/develop`.

Comment: I don't agree about the first 3 commands but in fact I'll add the missing `fetch` and `switch` just to be on the safe side, as we can assume very little. And you're right of course about `origin/develop`.

Answer (score -1):

Note: **[ESC]** Means the escape key.

1. git log

Get the PREVIOUS LOG ID - (not the most recent, but the one before it)

2. git rebase -i PREVIOUS LOG ID
3. (type) i
4. (EDIT - Replace the word 'pick' with 'reword')
5. (type) [ESC] : wq
6. (type) i
7. (EDIT - the commit message to what you want it to be)
8. (type) [ESC] : wq
   Successfully rebased...

Comment: There maybe a better modern equivalent, but this atleast gives you some exposure to rebasing other options too.

Comment: Just curious - if the person who 'minused' this response, provide an alternative solution

Comment: Just guessing on the DV, but you are assuming OP is using vim, and also the steps appear to be incorrect? I see two sets of "wq" and also I don't see where the 2 commits are being squashed?